# Will iPhone remote earbuds work with 6th Gen iPod Nano?

Tags: ipod-nano

....will iPhone remote earbuds work with 6th Gen iPod Nano? My brief internet search (random Google searches, Apple forums) yielded no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does.  I just tried it the other day to see what it does.  The only thing that does not work is the mic.  It will control the play, pause, volume up and down.  Really sweet!

Comment: Thanks Ernie! I guess I'll get some more of these. Woulda been really sweet if they could squeeze a Bluetooth transmitter in there lol. Maybe in the next one.